# Python Pandas Series.to_sql() with index

Tags: python, sql, pandas, indexing

I'm using pandas great library but this operation seems not be working.
I just want to convert a simple pandas Series into a SQL table with `to_sql()` method.

```
my_series = pd.read_json("some_path", typ="series")
my_series.to_sql(**{
            "name": "atc_classes",
            "if_exists": "replace",
            "index": True,
            "index_label": "atc_code",
            "dtype": { "atc_code": String(16), "atc_class": string }
})
```

I keep having this error when creating index.

> "BLOB/TEXT column 'atc_code' used in key specification without a key length"

json looks like this

```
{
  "A": "Système digestif et métabolisme",
  "A01": "Préparations stomatologiques",
  "A01A": "preparations stomatologiques",
...
}
```

Tks for your help :)

Comment: also why string for index column? change it to int and you will be ok

Comment: or why are you giving it type at all,

Comment: because default column type seems to be BLOB/TEXT and you cannot build an index on this type.

Comment: you know that "index" option in to_sql command is to include index column from data frame , which basically is a row number ( 1, 2,3,4,5,...) , right?

Comment: Are you trying to define an index on the atc_code column of your db ? The to_sql method is not the right place for that, it should be defined on your database schema.
As the previous comments point, the index and index_label options should be used in order to inject the dataframe's row index as a new column, that you should name differently than other columns

Answer (score 0):

@Pibiche @eshirvana.
My series has an index. It's not a row number. It's a string: ["A", "A01", "A01A"].
I just wanted to use that index as a column named `code_atc` in my table.
Somehow I succeeded in doing it using the following workaround:

```
    serie = pd.read_json(fpath, typ="series")
    df = serie.to_frame("label_atc")
    df.index.set_names(names="code_atc", inplace=True)
    df.to_sql(**{
            "name": "atc_classes",
            "if_exists": "replace",
            "index": True,
            "dtype": { "code_atc": String(16), "classe_atc": string }
    })
```

Though, I still don't know why my first code did not work.